# R Aggregate and compute ratio

Tags: r

I have data with two columns, one being the date the other a value; like the 
    below.
    What I would like to do is to compute per date the ratio of lines where 
    value is positive versus number of lines for that date in R.
    Any clue?

```
Date      # Value
20180514  #   3
20180514  #  -1
20180514  #  -1
20180513  #   2
20180513  #   5
20180513  #  -1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your goals, but here is a tidy verse approach:

```
your_data <- data.frame("Date" = c(20180514,20180514,20180514,20180513,20180513,20180513),
                    Value = c(3, -1, -1, 2, 5, -1))

library(tidyverse)

your_data %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(n_pos = sum(Value > 0), n_neg = sum(Value < 0), ratio = n_pos/n_neg)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Date n_pos n_neg ratio
 <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 20180513     2     1 2.00 
2 20180514     1     2 0.500
```

Answer (score 0):

Base `aggregate` will do an operation on columns within grouping features:

```
aggregate( dat['Value'], dat['Date'], function(x=Value) sum( x >0)/length(x) )
      Date     Value
1 20180513 0.6666667
2 20180514 0.3333333
```

Comment: Thanks!
Works like a charm and very elegant!